# How parent component calls method of its child in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, inheritance

As far i know, inheritance lets the child to use properties/methods of parent. But while R&D, i found a code segment where the parent component also using child components method. I searched for it, but haven't found proper explanation behind this. Here is the code:

Form Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Input from "./input";

class Form extends React.Component{
    state = {
        data: {},
        errors: {}
    };

    handleChange = ({currentTarget: input}) => {
        const data = {...this.state.data};
        data[input.name] = input.value;
        this.setState({data});
    };

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        //Some validation
        this.doSubmit();
    };

    renderInput(name, label, type) {
        const {data,errors} = this.state;
        return (
            <Input
                type={type}
                name={name}
                label={label}
                value={data[name]}
                error={errors[name]}
                onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        );
    };

    renderButton(label) {
        return (
            <button>{label}</button>
        );
    }
}

export default Form;
```

Login Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Form from "./common/form";

class Login extends Form{
    state = {
        data: {
            username: "",
            password: "",
        },
        errors: {},
    };

    doSubmit = () => {
        console.log(this.state.data);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    {this.renderInput("username", "Username", "text")}
                    {this.renderInput("password", "Password", "password")}
                    {this.renderButton("Submit")}
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Input Component:

```
import React from 'react';

const Input = ({name, label, error, ...rest}) => {
    return (
        <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
            <input className="from-control" {...rest} name={name} id={name}/>
            {error && <div>{error}</div>}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Input;
```

Here, **Login** component extends **Form** Component. For that reason, **Login** can use methods of **Form**. But how **Form** uses `doSubmit()` method of **Login** in its `handleSubmit` method?

Comment: That is because `Login extends Form` and if you're only using instances of `Login` you'll end up with a component that has all the methods of `Form` and `Login`.

Comment: By the way, this is not recommended in React (extending your own classes), even if it was, is not a good idea to use in super methods of the class that extends it.

Comment: Here, `Form` is what you would call an "abstract class", and `doSubmit()` is an "abstract method". Since JavaScript doesn't have true abstract classes, this is only reflected by the fact the base class is not directly used.

Comment: can you provide me some documentation, that explains this fact broadly. @PatrickRoberts @ Titus

Comment: [This doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) is about Inheritance in React and since Javascript doesn't yet supports abstract classes, I don't think there is any documentation on that.